# Locking a MySQL INNODB row in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, innodb, mariadb, xtradb

I have a table called `meta`, with two columns `name` and `value`.

In a php script, which is called by many clients concurrently, I do this:-

`$mysqli->multi_query("SELECT id FROM links WHERE id > (SELECT value FROM meta WHERE name='scan') LIMIT 1000;UPDATE meta SET value=value+1000 WHERE name='scan';");`

or this:-

`$mysqli->multi_query("SELECT id FROM links WHERE id > (SELECT value FROM meta WHERE name='scan' <b>FOR UPDATE</b>) LIMIT 1000;UPDATE meta SET value=value+1000 WHERE name='scan';");`

Unfortunately, this doesn't appear to work as clients are ending up with duplicate `id`'s. The database is heavily loaded and the `SELECT` takes a few seconds.

Comment: im confused as to what your trying to achieve

Comment: Well I have billions of rows in a table called links, and many clients are requesting a cluster of them to work on (distributed computing). So each worker client should have a 1000 unique id's. When each worker has finished processing them, they request the next batch, and so on. Of course, having 2 worker clients both work on the same id numbers is a waste of resources which I'm trying to avoid with a lock around the meta table update, which stores the current cursor position for issuing more jobs to worker clients.

Comment: couldn't you allocate the specific ids to the specific clients in the links table

Comment: no, because the number of clients are variable, and their run times are also variable.

Comment: your already doing it by tracking where they are at in the meta table, moving it to links means you can specify unallocated ids, so never get duplicates.

Comment: The meta table tracks where they (as in, ALL my clients) are at. it's a global cursor. It doesn't, and cannot track where each individual client is at. I can't allocate ID's to clients in advance, because as I've said before the number of clients is unknown. Think of this problem like seti@home.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);
$mysqli->query("BEGIN;");
$mysqli->multi_query("SELECT id FROM links WHERE id > (SELECT value FROM meta WHERE name='scan' FOR UPDATE) LIMIT 1000;UPDATE meta SET value=value+1000 WHERE name='scan';");
$mysqli->commit();
```

It's a complex issue; locking and transaction levels, but the magic above was the `BEGIN` statement. Without it, each statement was running in its own transaction level, and the `FOR UPDATE` lock was being unlocked too early.

Answer (score 1):

First try below experiment and then try to map as per your requirement.

Create table:

```
CREATE TABLE `t1` (                       
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,                 
  `notid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,                         
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)                                    
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Then create:

create rowlocking.php

```
<?php
    require_once('connectvars.php');
    // Connect to the database 
    $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

    $query = "START TRANSACTION";
    $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE id=5 FOR UPDATE";
    $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($data) != 0) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
        echo $row['id'];
        echo $row['notid'];
    }

    //$query = "COMMIT";
    //$data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
    sleep(10);
    echo "After 10 seconds";
?>
```

Above script will access a row with id=5 and locks for other transaction till 10 second sleeping time.

create rowlocking1.php

```
  <?php
    require_once('connectvars.php');
    // Connect to the database 
    $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

    $query = "START TRANSACTION";
    $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE id=5 FOR UPDATE";
    $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($data) != 0) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
        echo $row['id'];
        echo $row['notid'];
    }
    //sleep(10);
    //$query = "COMMIT";
    //$data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
    //echo "After 10 seconds";
?>
```

Above script tries to access same row with id=5.

Now if your run script rowlocking and within that 10 second sleeping time if you run rowlocking1 it will not able to access row id=5 till its release by rowlocking. Once 10 sec sleep time over rowlocking will be able to access row id=5.

Try to map this concept with your script you will get innoDB row level locking. Give a comment if you need detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
query("SELECT id FROM links WHERE id > (SELECT value FROM meta WHERE name='scan' LOCK IN SHARE MODE) LIMIT 1000 LOCK IN SHARE MODE;
UPDATE meta SET value=value+1000 WHERE name='scan';");
```

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for or not, but if so remember to unlock tables afterward when/where necessary and make sure that the account you are using has LOCK privileges.

[MySQL Documentation on INNODB READ LOCKS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html)

Comment: this hung my server - each query took forever.