# MariaDB. Use Transaction Rollback without locking tables

Tags: mysql, transactions, mariadb, rollback

On a website, when a user posts a comment I do several queries, Inserts and Updates. (On MariaDB 10.1.29)

I use `START TRANSACTION` so if any query fails at any given point I can easily do a rollback and delete all changes.
Now I noticed that this **locks the tables when I do an `INSERT` from an other `INSERT`**, and I'm not talking while the query is running, that’s obvious, but **until the transaction is not closed**.

Then `DELETE` is only locked if they share a common index key (comments for the same page), but luckily `UPDATE` is no locked.

Can I do any Transaction that does not lock the table from new inserts (while the transaction is ongoing, not the actual query), or any other method that lets me conveniently "undo" any query done after some point?

PD:

I start Transaction with PHPs function `mysqli_begin_transaction()` without any of the `flags`, and then `mysqli_commit()`.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MariaDB? What version? Please [edit] your question and show us the DDL of the table(s) in question and the code in your transaction.

Comment: @Dave I think I added all you asked for

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4982594/5260982) may be helpful. Since you know what row(s) you are going to be updating perhaps a `select with update` for that row would only lock that row instead of the table.

Comment: Which table is locked and for how long?

Comment: @Paul ‘comment’ table does not accept any INSERT, until the transaction is closed (if there is an INSERT on the transaction). I showcased the comments table since its simpler, but the same happens when publishing Posts, where I do about 8 queries (multiple INSERTS) and I also move files on the server, so until all is not completed correctly I do not commit, in that case locking time is higher, it’s not much maybe 1 second, but if I wait 40 second to COMMIT, that’s 40 seconds locked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that a simple INSERT would block other inserts for longer than the insert time. [AUTO_INC locks](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html) are not held for the full transaction time.

But if two transactions try to UPDATE the same row like in the following statement (two replies to the same comment)

```
UPDATE comment SET replies=replies+1 WHERE com_id = ?
```

the second one will have to wait until the first one is committed. You need that lock to keep the count (replies) consistent.

I think all you can do is to keep the transaction time as short as possible. For example you can prepare all statements before you start the transaction. But that is a matter of milliseconds. If you transfer files and it can take 40 seconds, then you shouldn't do that while the database transaction is open. Transfer the files before you start the transaction and save them with a name that indicates that the operation is not complete. You can also save them in a different folder but on the same partition. Then when you run the transaction, you just need to rename the files, which should not take much time. From time to time you can clean-up and remove unrenamed files.

Comment: I finally figured out that the only thing that was locking during the whole transaction was the UPDATES as you said, and only the targeted rows. 
Now I do everything I can before the transaction, and if it’s necessary after, and I add all UPDATES just before the commit, much better now.

Answer (score 1):

All write operations work in similar ways -- They lock the *rows* that they touch (or might touch) from the time the statement is executed until the transaction is closed via either `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`.  `SELECT...FOR UPDATE` and `SELECT...WITH SHARED LOCK` also get involved.

When a write operation occurs, deadlock checking is done.

In some situations, there is "gap" locking.  Did `com_id` happen to be the last id in the table?

Did you leave out any `SELECTs` that needed `FOR UPDATE`?